# C# multiple OR conditions in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, .net-5, sql-to-linq-conversion

I am trying to link multiple values OR in a loop with LINQ.

### Situation

Plattform: `.net 5` `C# 9`

We are building a filter logic for a list. In the current case it concerns string values which are to be filtered.
The user can search for one or more values. He can decide if the single search terms are AND/OR linked and if a value is negated.

I saw this entry. But since my values are in the loop, I can't use `||`.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37195788/1847143

Example:

- All animals with "A" in the name
  `SELECT * FROM "Animal" WHERE "Name" = 'A';`
- All animals with "A" or "B" in the name
  `SELECT * FROM "Animal" WHERE "Name" = 'A' OR "Name" = 'B';`
- All animals with "A" or "B" or NOT "C" in the name (This would be a meaningless search)
  `SELECT * FROM "Animal" WHERE "Name" = 'A' OR "Name" = 'B' OR "Name" != 'C' ;`
- All animals with "A" and "B" in the name
  `SELECT * FROM "Animal" WHERE "Name" = 'A' AND "Name" = 'B';`
- All animals with "A" and "B" and NOT "C" in the name
  `SELECT * FROM "Animal" WHERE "Name" = 'A' AND "Name" = 'B' AND "Name" != 'C';`

### Problem

The AND link with LINQ is no problem. But how can the values be linked with OR?

### Code Example

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SampleProject
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Or Condtion
            Condition condition = Condition.Or;

            var animalsQuery = Animals.AsQueryable();

            // Loop over all search values to extend the query
            foreach (FilterValue filterValue in FilterValues)
            {
                switch (filterValue.LikeType)
                {
                    case LikeType.Left: // LIKE '%value'
                        animalsQuery = filterValue.IsNegated
                            ? animalsQuery.Where(animal => !animal.Name.EndsWith(filterValue.Value))
                            : animalsQuery.Where(animal => animal.Name.EndsWith(filterValue.Value));

                        break;

                    case LikeType.Right: // LIKE 'value%'
                        animalsQuery = filterValue.IsNegated
                            ? animalsQuery.Where(animal => !animal.Name.StartsWith(filterValue.Value))
                            : animalsQuery.Where(animal => animal.Name.StartsWith(filterValue.Value));

                        break;

                    case LikeType.LeftAndRight: // LIKE '%value%'
                        animalsQuery = filterValue.IsNegated
                            ? animalsQuery.Where(animal => !animal.Name.Contains(filterValue.Value))
                            : animalsQuery.Where(animal => animal.Name.Contains(filterValue.Value));

                        break;

                    case LikeType.Equals: // Like 'value'
                        animalsQuery = filterValue.IsNegated
                            ? animalsQuery.Where(animal => animal.Name != filterValue.Value)
                            : animalsQuery.Where(animal => animal.Name == filterValue.Value);
                        break;
                }
            }

            var result = animalsQuery.ToList();
        }

        /// Values to filter
        public static List<Animal> Animals = new()
        {
            new() {Name = "Lenny"},
            new() {Name = "Gideon"},
            new() {Name = "Shania"},
            new() {Name = "Jada"},
            new() {Name = "Kamil"},
            new() {Name = "Fariha"},
        };

        /// Search Values
        public static List<FilterValue> FilterValues = new()
        {
            new() {Value = "a", LikeType = LikeType.Left},
            new() {Value = "n", LikeType = LikeType.Right},
            new() {Value = "f", LikeType = LikeType.LeftAndRight},
            new() {Value = "k", LikeType = LikeType.Equals},
        };
    }

    public class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class FilterValue
    {
        public string   Value     { get; set; }
        public bool     IsNegated { get; set; }
        public LikeType LikeType  { get; set; }
    }

    public enum LikeType
    {
        Left         = 1,
        Right        = 2,
        LeftAndRight = 3,
        Equals       = 4,
    }

    public enum Condition
    {
        And = 1,
        Or  = 2,
    }
}
```

Comment: If the `OR` are all equals rather than not equals then the problem is easy - use `Contains` (i.e. have a `List<string>` of the values). That won't work so well with `!=` alas.

Comment: Rather than chaining multiple `Where` calls, create a lambda for each condition, combine those lambdas with `&&` and/or `||` operators and then make one `Where` call with the combined result.

Comment: You probably need a PredicateBuilder; that is, a class that can create and combine linq query predicates. It usually includes methods for OR, AND, NOT, XOR, TRUE and FALSE. Its inputs are the name of the properties or lambda getter expressions targeted to the item class ("Animal" in your example).

Comment: @mjwills But this way I cannot combine `StartsWith` with `EndsWith`.
All animals that "start with A" AND "end with E".  `SELECT * FROM "Animal" WHERE "Name" LIKE 'A%' AND "Name" LIKE '%E';`

Comment: @TheBigNeo That is correct.

Comment: @TheBigNeo - Are you clear with how the duplicate answers your question?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, thank you very much. Together with the answer from Marc Gravell it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets into the realm of expression-tree rewriting. The good news is: it isn't horribly complex *and* you can perform your negate step at the same time:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace SampleProject
{
    public class Program
    {
        static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Combine<T>(Condition condition, Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right, bool negateRight)
        {
            if (right is null) return left;
            if (left is null)
            {
                return negateRight ?
                    Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                         Expression.Not(right.Body), right.Parameters)
                    : right;
            }

            var leftP = left.Parameters.Single();
            var rightP = right.Parameters.Single();

            var rightBody = right.Body;
            if (!ReferenceEquals(leftP, rightP))
            {
                // swap all uses of rightP on rightBody to leftP
                // i.e. normalize on the parameter
                rightBody = new SwapVisitor(rightP, leftP).Visit(rightBody);
            }
            if (negateRight)
            {
                rightBody = Expression.Not(rightBody);
            }
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(condition switch
            {
                Condition.And => Expression.AndAlso(left.Body, rightBody),
                Condition.Or => Expression.OrElse(left.Body, rightBody),
                _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(condition)),
            }, left.Parameters);
        }

        class SwapVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
        {
            private readonly Expression _from, _to;
            public SwapVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
            {
                _from = from;
                _to = to;
            }
            public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
                => ReferenceEquals(node, _from) ? _to : base.Visit(node);
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Or Condtion
            Condition condition = Condition.Or;

            var animalsQuery = Animals.AsQueryable();
            // Loop over all search values to extend the query
            Expression<Func<Animal, bool>> predicate = null;
            foreach (FilterValue filterValue in FilterValues)
            {
                switch (filterValue.LikeType)
                {
                    case LikeType.Left: // LIKE '%value'
                        predicate = Combine(condition, predicate, animal => animal.Name.EndsWith(filterValue.Value), filterValue.IsNegated);

                        break;

                    case LikeType.Right: // LIKE 'value%'
                        predicate = Combine(condition, predicate, animal => animal.Name.StartsWith(filterValue.Value), filterValue.IsNegated);

                        break;

                    case LikeType.LeftAndRight: // LIKE '%value%'
                        predicate = Combine(condition, predicate, animal => animal.Name.Contains(filterValue.Value), filterValue.IsNegated);

                        break;

                    case LikeType.Equals: // Like 'value'
                        predicate = Combine(condition, predicate, animal => animal.Name == filterValue.Value, filterValue.IsNegated);
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (predicate is not null)
            {
                animalsQuery = animalsQuery.Where(predicate);
            }
            var result = animalsQuery.ToList();
        }

        /// Values to filter
        public static List<Animal> Animals = new()
        {
            new() { Name = "Lenny" },
            new() { Name = "Gideon" },
            new() { Name = "Shania" },
            new() { Name = "Jada" },
            new() { Name = "Kamil" },
            new() { Name = "Fariha" },
        };

        /// Search Values
        public static List<FilterValue> FilterValues = new()
        {
            new() { Value = "a", LikeType = LikeType.Left },
            new() { Value = "n", LikeType = LikeType.Right },
            new() { Value = "f", LikeType = LikeType.LeftAndRight },
            new() { Value = "k", LikeType = LikeType.Equals },
        };
    }

    public class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class FilterValue
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool IsNegated { get; set; }
        public LikeType LikeType { get; set; }
    }

    public enum LikeType
    {
        Left = 1,
        Right = 2,
        LeftAndRight = 3,
        Equals = 4,
    }

    public enum Condition
    {
        And = 1,
        Or = 2,
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly. There is a small bug at the beginning of `Combine`.
If the first/single `right` value comes `left == null` and `right != null` and `negateRight == true`, then `right` is not negated. ```if (left is null) return negateRight ? Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Not(right.Body), right.Parameters) : right;```

Comment: @TheBigNeo fair enough!